# Random Number Sort Arrays

Tags: java

For my java class, I have this problem: 
Write a program that generates 100 random integers in the range 0 to 25, and stores them in an array. Then, the program should call a class method that sorts the odd numbers into an array and returns the array. The program should then call another method that sorts the even numbers into a separate array and returns the array. Both arrays should then be displayed.

This is my code:

```
    public class Assignment8
     {
        public static void main(String [] args)
    {
    int [] randomNums = new int [100];
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNums.length; i++) { 
        randomNums[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 26); 
        int[] oddNums = sortOdd(randomNums);
        System.out.println("The odd numbers are "); 
        for (int n = 0; n<=oddNums.length; n++) { 
        System.out.print(n); 
        } 
        int[] evenNums = sortEven(randomNums);
        System.out.println("The even numbers are ");
        for (int o = 0; o<=evenNums.length; o++) { 
        System.out.print(o); 
        } 
    }
    }

     public static int[] sortOdd(int[] randomNums)
      {
    int numOdds = 0;
    for (int x : randomNums){
        if(x % 2 == 1){
        ++numOdds;
        }
    }
    int[] oddNums = new int[numOdds]; 
    int z = 0;
    for (int n : randomNums){
        if(n % 2 == 1){
            oddNums[z] = n;
            z++;
        }
    }
    return oddNums;


      } 
      public static int[] sortEven(int[] randomNums)
      {
    int numEvens = 0;
    for (int x : randomNums){
        if(x % 2 == 0){
        ++numEvens;
        }
    }
    int[] evenNums = new int[numEvens];
    int z = 0;
    for (int n : randomNums){
        if(n % 2 == 0){
            evenNums[z] = n;
            z++;
        }
    }
    return evenNums;

    }



    }
```

It is just printing out a bunch of numbers and the words "The even numbers are" and "The odd numbers are". What should I fix in my code to make it fulfill my assignment?

Comment: You're printing the `for` loop iterator, and not the value that is in the sorted array... I think you meant `System.out.print(oddNums[n]);` and same for the `evenNums`...

Comment: This is not the place to be asking people to complete your assignments for you really, I think you'll figure it out for yourself eventually, just keep trying. You'll probably find most people here will share a similar sort of attitude in that people here want you to learn for yourself rather than be told. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine, but you are missing a proper **sort methodology**, ascending or descending won't matter much, but the algorithm you choose to sort the array is unknown in this case. Let me introduce you to the **worst** method to sort an array, **bubble-sort** and there are many others like **Insertion Sort, Merge Sort, QuickSort, BucketSort etc etc**, built-in java methods can handle sorts at super fast speeds, but for the sake of simplicity, take **bubble sort** as the sorting method, this is how it looks in code

```
public static void sortArray( int[] data )
{
    for( int x = 0; x < data.length; x++ )
    {
        for( int y = 0; y < data.length - 1; y++ )
        {
            if( data[y] < data[y + 1] )
            {
                int hold = data[y];
                data[y] = data[y + 1];
                data[y + 1] = hold;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Simply arranges the array in **descending** order. Now you would also like to generate a random array of fixed size, with elements no greater than 25. You should avoid your approach of generating such an array, because you are going to get simply 0's out of it, Math.random() is generating floating points, try this method to generate random array

```
public static int[] generateRandomArrayWithLimitAndSize( int limit , int size )
{
    final java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
    final int[] data = new int[size];
    for( int x = 0; x < data.length; x++ )
    {
        data[x] = rand.nextInt(limit);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Here is how you would have gone to sort even's

```
public static int[] sortEven( int[] data )
{
    int len = 0;
    int[] copyData;
    for( int x = 0; x < data.length; x++ )
    {
        if( data[x] % 2 == 0 )
        {
            len++;
        }
    }
    copyData = new int[len];
    for( int x = 0 , y = 0; x < data.length; x++ )
    {
        if( data[x] % 2 == 0 )
        {
            copyData[y++] = data[x];
        }
    }
    sortArray( copyData );
    return copyData;
}
```

You can well imagine what the code for **sortOdd** should have looked like. Now you can try to visualize the result by trying this

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] myArray = generateRandomArrayWithLimitAndSize( 25 , 100 ); // limit,size
    System.out.println( "Actual Array: " + java.util.Arrays.toString( myArray ) );
    System.out.println( "\r\nSorting Evens: \r\n" + java.util.Arrays.toString( sortEven( myArray ) ) );

    System.out.println( "\r\nSorting Odds: \r\n" + java.util.Arrays.toString( sortOdd( myArray ) ) );

}
```

And if you are still facing troubles in **You can well imagine what the code for sortOdd should have looked like** , then this is **sortOdd(int[])** definition

```
public static int[] sortOdd( int[] data )
{
    int len = 0;
    int[] copyData;
    for( int x = 0; x < data.length; x++ )
    {
        if( data[x] % 2 != 0 )
        {
            len++;
        }
    }
    copyData = new int[len];
    for( int x = 0 , y = 0; x < data.length; x++ )
    {
        if( data[x] % 2 != 0 )
        {
            copyData[y++] = data[x];
        }
    }
    sortArray( copyData );
    return copyData;
}
```

Open to further questions if any, but all this should work fine for you

Comment: Thank You so much that helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Assignment8
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int [] randomNums = new int [100];

        for (int i = 0; i < randomNums.length; i++) 
        { 
            randomNums[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 26); 
            System.out.println(randomNums[i] +"\n");
        }

        Integer[] oddNums = sortOdd(randomNums);
        System.out.println("The odd numbers are "); 

        for (int n = 0; n< oddNums.length; n++)
        { 
            System.out.print(oddNums[n] +"\n"); 
        } 

        Integer[] evenNums = sortEven(randomNums);
        System.out.println("The even numbers are ");

        for (int o = 0; o< evenNums.length; o++) 
        { 
            System.out.print(evenNums[o] + "\n"); 
        } 
    }

    public static Integer[] sortOdd(int[] randomNums)
    {
        List<Integer> oddNums = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int x : randomNums){
            if(x % 2 == 1){
              oddNums.add(x);
            }
         }
        return oddNums.toArray(new Integer[oddNums.size()]);
    } 

    public static Integer[] sortEven(int[] randomNums)
    {
        List<Integer> evenNums = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int x : randomNums){
                if(x % 2 == 0){
                    evenNums.add(x);
                }
            }
        return evenNums.toArray(new Integer[evenNums.size()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed rather than just posting a block of code?

Comment: I missed to add the sorting. But I have changed that to print the odd and even number. May be use a diff to see whats changed

Comment: Sorry, I meant in your post so that others can easily see what was done to achieve your answer

Comment: I tried first time in slack overflow. I will learn this going forward. Its my mistake.